# Intermittent wireless connection while on battery

Tags: wireless-networking

On my HP m6-k015dx Sleekbook, the internet connection works perfect on AC power, but when I unplug, it keeps disconnecting.

**How I verified**

I do a ping test

```
ping -t google.com
```

When on AC power there is no disconnection, but when on battery I get the following repeating pattern:

```
Reply from 74.125.68.139: bytes=32 time=150ms TTL=44
Reply from 74.125.68.139: bytes=32 time=150ms TTL=44
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 74.125.68.139: bytes=32 time=300ms TTL=44
Reply from 74.125.68.139: bytes=32 time=142ms TTL=44
Reply from 74.125.68.139: bytes=32 time=166ms TTL=44
Reply from 74.125.68.139: bytes=32 time=152ms TTL=44
Reply from 74.125.68.139: bytes=32 time=258ms TTL=44
Reply from 74.125.68.139: bytes=32 time=172ms TTL=44
Reply from 74.125.68.139: bytes=32 time=183ms TTL=44
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
```

**What I have tried**

I have Windows 10 (Upgraded 2 months back. It has been working fine.) and have tried the updated drivers from HP's official website but it didn't work. I have been seeing this issue for 2 days. Don't remember if I dropped or knocked it somewhere.

**My Questions**

Is it a hardware issue?

Will downgrading to Windows 8 help?

Comment: I reinstalled windows which caused all the drivers to reinstall as well, now its fixed, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options`, click on `Change plan settings` for your selected plan, then `Change advanced power settings` and under `Wireless Adapter Settings` you can set it to `Maximum Performance`